# how to delete empty namespace from child element in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I am trying to delete empty namespace from the child element. I tried with following code but its not deleting

```
SET @xDocTemp.modify('declare default element namespace "mynamepsace"; 
delete /worksh/Data/row[@xmlns=""]')
```

xml data:

```
<worksh xmlns="mynamespace">
  <Data>
    <row r="1" ht="18">
    <row xmlns="" rl="39" spans="2">
    <row xmlns="" rl="39" spans="2">
 </Data>
<worksh>
```

Expected output

```
<worksh xmlns="mynamespace">
  <Data>
    <row rl="1" ht="18">
    <row rl="39" spans="2">
    <row rl="39" spans="2">
 </Data>
<worksh>
```

Comment: not sure if it's possible with `modify()`, but you can just replace it like `set @xDocTemp = select cast(replace(cast(@xDocTemp as nvarchar(max)), ' xmlns=""', '') as xml)`

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it's possible with `modify()`, but you can just replace it like

```
set @xDocTemp = select cast(replace(cast(@xDocTemp as nvarchar(max)), ' xmlns=""', '') as xml)
```